# is there a groovy logical not operator (like unaryNot..) that can be overloaded

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, logical-operators

I have a Rule class in groovy and i can overload <<, and, or for class instance but if i want to write

```
Rule a = new Rule()
a<< {false }  //overloaded evaluate internal closure 

println !a // expect to get true - but you always get false
```

i cant find what the groovy logical 'not' operator is.    If i call '!a' i always get false as i think that compiler is using  groovy truth of  'a' is 'true' so '!a' would be false.

but i want the '!a' to mean '!(a.evaluate())' for this class

how do i do that ?

PS - extended - here is dummy mocked up view of my Rule class - all trimmings removed - this is runnable in a script

```
class Rule {
    Closure  evaluate
    def leftShift (closure ) {
        this.evaluate = closure
    }


}

def r = new Rule ()
r << {false}

println "logical not of rule : " + !r
println " rule evaluate  : " + !r.evaluate ()

r << {true}
println "logical not of rule : " + !r
println " rule evaluate  : " + !r.evaluate ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `asBoolean` to be mapped to your `evaluate` method ?

With this, you'll have :

```
Rule rule = new Rule()
..
if (rule) { // rule.evaluate()
}

if (!rule) { // !rule.evaluate()
}
```

If you are adventurous enough, you can implement a custom ASTTransformation in order to add your operator in the language. Visit the ClassNode to find `NotExpression` and transform this expression into a `MethodCallExpression`.

Comment: hah that sounds promising - i didnt see that method in the overload operators list in my book - that might just do the job - let me have a crack, writing an AST desont feel right as then i'd have to put an annotation onto the class - i'll think about that also - but that first suggestion may be closeEnough

Comment: You can use AST without annotation, you can just add the transformation in the compiler configuration (when you load a script for example), but I must admit it's not an easy task :-)

Comment: yes, whilst the example was mocked up in script, the real thing is extending someones library classes, so its really going to in code probbably more than script.  The AST is trickey - and you dont want to get it wrong.  It cant be a global transformation, it would just have to be for this class.  i've played with the asBoolean () idea and that seems to do what i want - so thanks you very much for that.  I hant thought of overloading asType() construct.  Think this is best way for now, though whether as noted above there should be a `unaryNot` action in the GDK is interesting one to pose

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the list of [Operator Overloading](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading) in the documentation.

Think the best you could do, is re-purpose one of the overloadable ones.

Maybe if you gave a runnable example, more specific help could be given.

---

So you could overload one of the available operators, like `bitwiseNegate`:

Add the following to `Rule`:

```
def bitwiseNegate() {
    return !evaluate()
}
```

and then you can do:

```
println ~r
```

Comment: Tim - mocked up a simple representation of Rule class that you can run - I want to overload the '!r' behaviour for Rule and dont know the operator name to do that

Comment: you can sort of do something - add a `call() {evaluate()}` method then i can write `println !r() `  but that looks ugly - but forces the evaluate() to be executed in the rule

Comment: There is no operator name for `!`

Comment: Added an example of using bitwiseNegate instead (as that can be overloaded)

Comment: yes - thought about that but its not really the logical not operation.  I think i just have to write the full evaluate expression and logical not that.  It might have been nice to provide a `unaryNot` method to GDK does that sound a reasonable ask to put in as a suggestion or am i barking up the wrong tree